# Summarize posts within a period | slow Query | order temporaray

Tags: mysql, performance

```
SELECT FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date, '%Y-%m-%d'))) / 86400) AS arrIndex,
count(post_id) AS qty
FROM xf_post
WHERE user_id = 1
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date, '%Y-%m-%d') > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY arrIndex
```

I have massive problems with this query. With more than 50k entries it gets slow up to several seconds. Problem seems to be "group by" here. this problem also exists on different servers

```
Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Index exists on "post_date" and "user_id. Sense of the query:All contributions of a certain time period should be counted. The post_date field is available as a timestamp.

Can the query be optimized?
Thanks for suggestions

Comment: *`FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date, '%Y-%m-%d'))) / 86400)`* - why so complex? use `TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, CURRENT_DATE, FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date))`. *Can the query be optimized?* No in current state. But you may add generated column `AS (DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date)))`, index it and use for filtering and grouping.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DATE(post_date),
        COUNT(*) AS qty
    FROM  xf_post
    WHERE  user_id = 1
      AND  post_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    GROUP BY  arrIndex
```

And have a composite index in this order (the `=` first, the 'range' last):

```
INDEX(user_id, post_date)
```

(Note that I changed `>` to `>=`.)